# Une traduction de la locution néerlandaise « handjeklap doen met »

Tags: locutions, néerlandais

J’espère que vous pouvez traduire l’emploi figuré de « la main chaude » qui je décris ici. (Je vous préviens que la traduction mot à mot est peut-être faible. )

La locution a trait à deux partis qui travaillent ensemble de quelque façon. Un d’eux est bienveillant et puissant, un pays bien vu peut-être (A). L’autre nuit au bien-être des gens, pensez à un état corrompu (B). Si le parti A a besoin de B pour parvenir à ses fins, il peut choisir de traiter avec lui, quitte à mécontenter des gens qui sont contre cette façon d’agir. Ils peuvent dire qu’on *joue à la main chaude* avec quelqu’un ou quelque chose qui ne mérite pas d’être soutenu.

**Deux exemples**

Il y a quelques années, les Pays-Bas voulaient se défaire d’une espèce de vieux chars qui n’étaient plus à la hauteur d’une bataille contemporaine. Le gouvernement voulait alors les vendre à l’Indonésie, bien que l’on soupçonnât que ce pays enfreignait les droits de l’homme. On disait que « les Pays-Bas faisaient la main chaude avec un état nuisible. »

Quand un contrevenant qui a des liaisons avec des malfaiteurs, il est parfois moins longtemps enfermé s’il les dénonce. Bien que ce soit une façon de déraciner des réseaux criminels, on trouve cette entraide honteuse. On parle de la main chaude avec des fripons.

Comment: @M42, Je suis désolé de ne pas avoir dit que cette locution légèrement familière, et qu’elle sous-entend un peu de mépris. Ce que vous et clr m’avez donné semble traduire « handjeklap doen met » assez bien, mais je ne sais pas s’il y a des locutions argotiques qui sont plus fort apparentées à la locution néerlandaise. Vôtre avis sur le son de « compromission » et « se compromettre avec » m’importe.

Comment: J'ai ajouté quelques synonymes moins soutenus dans ma réponse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Compromission](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compromission) me semble convenir à la description donnée.

Extrait du TFLi :

> − Spéc., péj. Action de transiger avec sa conscience ou ses principes en acceptant certains accommodements avec d'autres personnes pour son intérêt personnel (son ambition, ses passions ou sa tranquillité).

Avec une tournure moins « diplomatique », on peut utiliser :

- [Manigancer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manigancer)
- [Fricoter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fricoter)
- [Magouiller](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/magouiller)

Comment: - "Les Pays-Bas *se compromettent* avec un état nuisible." - "La police prends des *arrangements* avec les repentis."

Answer (score 0):

Dans un contexte diplomatique, on parle de *Realpolitik*.